# Button to create new site

Tags: 2010, site

Looking to see how I could create a button on a SharePoint page that would create a new site. I know this can be done through Site Actions and a couple more clicks, but I want to make it intuitive for the user to just click a button and essentially do the same thing as it would navigating through Site Actions...

Comment: Not out of the box. Can you use Visual Studio or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to do the following

- Edit your page that you need to add the link button .
- Add  content Editor.
- From the above ribbon click on Edit Source.
- Add the following code to create a link to open in the model dialog to create a new website.(or add your final link that navigating through Site Actions)

> ```
> <script>
>     function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
>     var options = {
>         url: pageUrl,
>         title: 'Create New Site',
>         allowMaximize: false,
>         showClose: true,
>         width: 700,
>         height: 500
>     };
>     SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
>     }
>       
>     </script>
>
>  <a onclick="openDialog("http://yourrootsite/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx");"
>  href="#">Create New Site</a>
> ```

OutPut

[image]

Check also the detail steps that matched with your situation at [Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hi! This doesn't seem to be working for me. Maybe because this is 2013 and I am using 2010? Is there another way? Thank you!

Comment: what's your issue now my bro ?! you only need to put your final link URL and I tried in both 2010 and 2013 and worked properly

Comment: I changed the final link URL and tested it but the link doesn't do anything. I went back into the CEWP and it changed the whole thing to this: <script>


    function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
    var options = {
        url: pageUrl,
        title: 'Create New Site',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        width: 700,
        height: 500
    };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
    }

    </script><a onclick="openDialog(" href="#">Create New Site</a>

Comment: try to use this  in cewp var options = {  
  url:'/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx',
  title:'Title, Description, and Icon',
  width:640,
  height:400
}

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it still isn't working. I do not have a TeamViewer but thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44216/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-jackie).